# VS Code attempting to use internal repository and failing

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-code

I am working on a practice application in vs code at the moment and failing at the first hurdle. I am trying to add json configuration with the following command:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
```

from the terminal within vs code which I have started as an admin. I am getting the error:

```
error: Unable to load the service index for source <URL to internal nuget repository>.
```

which is an internal repository that we use in some of our projects for exposing our own packages. So it appears that VS Code is picking up on my package settings and I need to change this so I can target nuget.org. Where do I control this item from so that I can still pick it up in Visual Studio but I don't get it by default when using VS Code?

I have also tried:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json -s https://www.nuget.org/
```

which still errors but with a not found and then referencing the internal repository again.

How do I control VS Code so that it does not attempt the internal repo?

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer seems to be relatively simple. All I neded to do was install

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jmrog.vscode-nuget-package-manager

and use the command pallette and it all worked properly. It would be nice to get an explanation of what has happened here if anyone knows.